# How do I make Angular 2 routing work with App Engine on page refresh?

Tags: google-app-engine, angular

I am trying to make an Angular 2 app running on App Engine Standard Environment. It works with the following `app.yaml` configuration when navigating within the app:

```
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static

- url: (.*)
  static_files: static\1
  upload: static
```

I can click on a link from `/` to `/clients` or `/clients/234234` and it works fine.

However if I **refresh** the browser in a non base path e.g. `http://myapp.appspot.com/clients/234234` then I get a 404 error. I guess I need to serve my `index.html` from all paths which is what I thought `(.*)/` and `(.*)` would do.

How can I set up my handlers/app so I can use HTML5 routing and not let this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a bunch of static files that need to be served so I added their mappings first. I also (most importantly) changed the way index.html was served:

```
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /(.*\.svg)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.svg)

- url: /(.*\.js)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.map)
  mime_type: application/octet-stream
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.map)

- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static

- url: (.*)
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static
```