# Angular 2 & Google App Engine, set base href, reloading child routes fails, server-side routing

Tags: google-app-engine, angular, angular2-routing

**EDIT**: See answer below. This was a server-side issue due to routing in Google App Engine, not a client-side related issue.

I have an Angular-CLI ng2 app where I've set the `<base href="/admin/">`

When routing, everything works perfectly as it should. However, when I am on a child route such as `/admin/forms` and I reload the page, I get a 404 error that the resource is unavailable.

From `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from "./main/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {AdminComponent} from "./main/admin/admin.component";
import {FormsComponent} from "./main/components/forms/forms.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'forms',
        component: FormsComponent
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

From Console error log:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/admin/forms
```

Server-side routing using app.yaml (Google App Engine):

```
handlers:
- url: /admin/(.+)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
- url: .*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

The error only occurs on page reload from the child route or trying to access the url directly. When accessing the route from a sidenav service, the page loads correctly.

Comment: Could you please add your routes, we aren't mind readers :P

Comment: `404` is definitely a server side issue. Please post the exact error message.

Comment: If the server reports 404 "http://localhost:8080/admin/forms" not found, it can only mean 2 things. The request is not redirected to `index.html` or `index.html` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeap, confirmed it has to be server-side. Works when the app is run via ng serve. Will look into further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm linking [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312010/how-do-i-make-angular-2-routing-work-with-app-engine-on-page-refresh) as well as [jay khimani's blog](https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/10/deploying-angular-2-app-with-angular.html) as to why I was getting the errors.

The errors had nothing to do with Angular 2, but with an incorrect ordering of regular expressions in Google App Engine's app.yaml handlers.

I initially used Jay's blog to set up my app.yaml handlers to be:

```
handlers:
  - url: /admin/(.+)
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.*)
  - url: .*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

However, any routes that I would manually load would be caught by the first regex expression (`/admin/(.+)`). Therefore, I changed the routing for serving my static files to be more specific:

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(js|map|css|png))$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*\.(js|map|css|png)$

  - url: .*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

This solved route page-reload issues for me.