# Angular page shows 404 when refreshed - error only occurs on Google Cloud

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, http-status-code-404

I'm working on an Angular project for GCP (using App Engine + Storage, no Docker stuff yet) and I'm having a problem when I refresh one of the pages.

This is a search engine on index.html that displays the results on the “page” domain.com/results. I can get to the results page; back through the browser; go back through the interface I created…no problem. The problem occurs when I refresh the results page:

[image]

This sounds strange to me because, both locally and on AWS, the same project runs smoothly. It only breaks when I use GCP - which is the project's official cloud.

Here's my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

    handlers:
    - url: /
      static_files: skote/index.html
      upload: skote/index.html

    - url: /
      static_dir: skote
```

And my folder structure on Storage:

```
bucket
├─ skote/
│  ├─ assets/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ lot-of-files-in-css-js
├─ app.yaml
```

I await help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39312010/8753991). If your app's routing works well, try adding a configuration to your `app.yaml` in handlers element that will allow other static files to serve to your application. For example:

**app.yaml**:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
 # allow any file with an extension.
- url: /(.*\.(.+))$
  static_files: /\1
  upload: skote/(.*\.(.+))$

- url: /
  static_files: skote/index.html
  upload: skote/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: skote
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I had seen this topic and even tested this implementation, but unfortunately it didn't work: the same error occurs.

Comment: I tried simple app on my end and there's no problem with it. Perhaps you can provide a copy of your sample app or how can we reproduce your issue? Do you serve your static files from the Cloud Storage bucket?

Comment: We serve the application in static format, yes.
Considering the urgency, I ended up solving the problem by changing the deployment approach: I deployed it to Firebase and it works like a charm.